# Analize an image taken with a custom camera, with Tensorflow Lite. (Xamarin)

Tags: android, tensorflow, xamarin, android-camera, tensorflow-lite

It's a cross-platform project in VS 19, but for now, I'm starting with Android.

I have found tons of repos. of apps that open the native camera software of your device and then analyze it, and throw the result. But I want to take that picture, from a custom camera.
I found [one](https://github.com/OsmarICancino/XamarinCameraRender) in GitHub that could be useful as a base for it, and want to take the image taken by it and pass it through the TF lite model (locally).

The code is pretty straight forward, this is the part were it take photo action is (Android):

```
       async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera.StopPreview();

        var image = textureView.Bitmap;

        try
        {
            var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            var folderPath = absolutePath + "/Camera";
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("photo_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            image.Recycle();

            var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            intent.SetData(uri);
            MainActivity.Instance.SendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"               ", ex.Message);
        }

        camera.StartPreview();
    }
```

So, from then, it would open a new activity showing the photo that was taken and the given prediction.

Any idea of how to fetch the image given (taken the path, as passing the bitmap I suppose would be really slow) and (most importantly) make a prediction out of it in the new activity?

I'm basing myself with [this](https://github.com/Veroni4ka/XamarinTensorFlowApp) TFLite project (although, as I said, it opens the native camera) as to code the model.

Comment: Have you looked into using the new CameraX which gives you an easy option of taking video/photo stream and running ML like TF lite?  https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze

Comment: Wow @AnonAnonym, looks pretty like what I was looking for. But look's like is only a Kotlin/ Java thing, but I'm looking for a multi-platform app, that's why I'm using Xamarin. Do you know if is there a similar concept, for IOS? Or if is that framework available for c# development?

Comment: I have no idea about iOS.  In android I can't of think of anything but CameraX.  Android has the ability to use the NDK, but that will be in C++, not C# and will be a much more difficult task because you will have to take into account different phones and different cameras with different specs.  As for something that will work across iOs and Android probably not.  This stuff is relatively new and needs to use device specific hardware.  The operating systems aren't the same.  You're probably going to have to custom code in Kotlin/Java and Swift and learn both OS if you want cross platform.